# Can not pass parameter into Curl Command as Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

Same curl command is not working with bash script.
Could anyone ple

Console try (successful one):

```
curl -ki \
  --cookie cookie-jar.txt \
  --header 'Content-Type: text/xml' \
  --request POST https://testserver:1234/v1/secondarylogin \
  --data '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:secondaryloginrequest xmlns:p="http://www.ericsson.com/em/am/co/authentication/v1_0/">
    <credential>
        <secret>6673</secret>
        <type>otp</type>
    </credential>
    <channelinformation>COMVIVAAGENTAPP</channelinformation>
</p:secondaryloginrequest>' 

**HTTP/1.1 200 OK**
Date: Wed, 02 Mar 2022 10:52:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 02 Mar 2022 10:52:02 GMT
Set-Cookie: sessionid=default0c07b834d30644e9b30a9bfced82e6f2
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

A very simple Bash Script (failed one):

sh sectest.sh 6673

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
curl -ki \
  --cookie cookie-jar.txt \
  --header 'Content-Type: text/xml' \
  --request POST https://ugtestpo:8446/v1/secondarylogin \
  --data '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:secondaryloginrequest xmlns:p="http://www.ericsson.com/em/am/co/authentication/v1_0/">
    <credential>
        <secret>"$1"</secret>
        <type>otp</type>
    </credential>
    <channelinformation>COMVIVAAGENTAPP</channelinformation>
</p:secondaryloginrequest>'

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Wed, 02 Mar 2022 10:47:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 188
```

I can not pass my secret value with paramatically.

Comment: Change secret line with `<secret>'"$1"'</secret>`

Comment: Please ignore URLs, they are same in fact.

Comment: Note also, that in the way you run your script, it is not executed by bash. This doesn't matter for your simple case, but may bite you one day, when you are going to extend it and want to use bash-specific language features.

Comment: In addition to the comment by _anubhava_, I would for the safe side verify that `$1` indeed consists only of digits. This would make detecting simple format errors in the script invocation easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

Following should work for you with proper quoting that allows `$1` to expand:

```sh
curl -ki \
  --cookie cookie-jar.txt \
  --header 'Content-Type: text/xml' \
  --request POST https://ugtestpo:8446/v1/secondarylogin \
  --data '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:secondaryloginrequest xmlns:p="http://www.ericsson.com/em/am/co/authentication/v1_0/">
    <credential>
        <secret>'"$1"'</secret>
        <type>otp</type>
    </credential>
    <channelinformation>COMVIVAAGENTAPP</channelinformation>
</p:secondaryloginrequest>'
```

Comment: Yes, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

For readability, I'd assign the xml to a variable: heredocs are helpful to avoid quoting hell.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

payload=$(cat <<END_XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:secondaryloginrequest xmlns:p="http://www.ericsson.com/em/am/co/authentication/v1_0/">
    <credential>
        <secret>$1</secret>
        <type>otp</type>
    </credential>
    <channelinformation>COMVIVAAGENTAPP</channelinformation>
</p:secondaryloginrequest>
END_XML
)

curl -ki \
  --cookie cookie-jar.txt \
  --header 'Content-Type: text/xml' \
  --request POST \
  --data "$payload" \
  https://ugtestpo:8446/v1/secondarylogin
```